# How to return both an int and a number in python use chr and ord?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to this so have mercy on my poor, stupid soul.

If you wanted to return a two-character ".com" with both a string and a string-and-a-string and a string and an int (ie: "ab.com" and "a7.com") how would you do it?

I've been looking at other code and I'm literally getting Japanese characters returned.

```
while letter1 <= 'z': # Outer loop
letter2 = 'a'
   while letter2 <= 'z': # Inner loop
        print('%s%s.com' % (letter1, letter2))
        letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)
        letter1 = chr(ord(letter1) + 1)
```

letter2 should be returning either a letter a-z or a number but it only gives me back whatever letter1 is ('aa, bb, cc, etc...')

Comment: ...what? That makes no sense.

Comment: It sounds like you might have an indentation problem, but I have no idea what you mean by "both an int and a number" or "both a string and a string-and-a-string and a string and an int".

Comment: You shouldn't increment letter1 in the inner while-loop.

Comment: As @michaelbutscher says, you need to de-indent the line that increments letter1

Comment: I phrased it like shit but I essentially need to return something like aa.com bb.com cc.com a7.com a4.com a9.com etc. I just don't know how to get letter2 to return either a letter or a number 1-9.

Comment: Also, if I deindent letter1 than the loop just goes on forever.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what this code is meant to do?

Comment: The code should print out "aa.com bb.com cc.com dd.com ee.com all the way through 'z'. By altering letter2 I should be able to have it print out a1.com a2.com c5.com etc. It should make it so that the second character can be either a number or an int.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, you can use `itertools.product` to generate this:

First, generate your alphabet. For this, I'm going to use `alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits` (in other words, a-z and 0-9).

If I say: `list(itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=2))`, we start getting what we're looking for:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('a', 'g'), ...]
```

So for example, your entire code could look like:

```
def domain_generator(alphabet, length, suffix):
    for first, second in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=length):
        yield '{}{}.{suffix}'.format(first, second, suffix=suffix)
```

where you can now iterate over the domain generator with:

```
for domain in domain_generator(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, 2, 'com'):
    print(domain)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. This is part puzzle though where none of the code can really be changed. I can only add what I need to make letter2 return an int 1-9 or a letter. So the result would be something like "aa.com" or "a9.com". Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is basically a list of all domains matching the regex `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9].com`.

Fiddling with the ASCII character value could be one way to implement this, but I think it would be more pythonic to try something like this instead:

```
import string
for letter1 in string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits:
  for letter2 in string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits:
     print('%s%s.com' % (letter1, letter2))
```